# Error: path for html_dependency not provided R Markdown selectInput

Tags: r, input, markdown

I have a problem with my R Markdown project.
I can not add a select input or even a sliderInput.
When I click Build Website I get this error message: Error: path for html_dependency not provided
Execution halted
I watch many topics but I can not solve my problem.

Can you help me ?
thank you in advance !

````
---
  title: "Untitled"
  author: "qc"
  date: "May 30, 2017"
  output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
```
````

### Inputs {.sidebar}

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}

inputPanel(
radioButtons("category",label= "Select  Category",choices=c("diffPts","diffGF","diffGA","diffGD","diffpos"),inline = TRUE),

selectInput("dataset","Choose :", 
              choices = c("ezce","efzf","zef"))



```
````

Answer (score 3):

First you were missing the runtime: shiny in the beginning of your Rmd file
Second you were missing closing ")" in the inputPanel

````html
---

title: "Untitled"
author: "qc"
date: "May 30, 2017"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
runtime: shiny

---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(datasets)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-------------------------------------
```{r, echo=FALSE}

inputPanel(radioButtons("category",label= "Select  Category",choices=c("diffPts","diffGF","diffGA","diffGD","diffpos"),inline = TRUE))



selectInput("dataset","Choose :", 
              choices = c("ezce","efzf","zef"))



```
````

Comment: But this does not solve the problem. The error still persists.

Answer (score 3):

This issue comes up when you use `rmarkdown::render` instead of `rmarkdown::run` which is required to run the Shiny server.

Comment: Do you know how to build a website though that includes shiny output in the rmarkdown chunks?