# How to run shiny app inside the flexdashboard

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm trying to incorporate shiny interactive sheet to my already existing flexdashboard.

Here is the data structure created using `dput()` function

```
structure(list(words1 = structure(c(1L, 10L, 19L, 20L, 7L, 8L, 
3L, 15L, 2L, 9L, 11L, 14L, 12L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 16L, 18L, 17L, 13L
), .Label = c("app", "can", "connect", "dont", "free", "get", 
"good", "great", "like", "map", "navig", "need", "one", "phone", 
"purchas", "road", "rout", "updat", "use", "work"), class = "factor"), 
    pct1 = c(70.8, 40.4, 26.4, 25.6, 22.7, 18.4, 13.7, 11.2, 
    10.8, 10.8, 10.8, 10.5, 10.5, 10.1, 9.4, 9.4, 9, 8.3, 8.3, 
    8.3), words2 = structure(c(1L, 18L, 8L, 19L, 16L, 4L, 17L, 
    5L, 15L, 12L, 14L, 6L, 3L, 11L, 20L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 7L, 13L
    ), .Label = c("app", "download", "get", "good", "great", 
    "just", "like", "map", "navig", "need", "now", "phone", "rout", 
    "time", "tom", "tomtom", "updat", "use", "work", "year"), class = "factor"), 
    pct2 = c(69.1, 32.9, 27.3, 25, 21.4, 20, 16.6, 16.2, 14.7, 
    13.1, 13, 13, 13, 12.7, 12.2, 11.8, 11.2, 10.4, 10.3, 10.2
    ), words3 = structure(c(1L, 17L, 8L, 19L, 16L, 4L, 12L, 14L, 
    2L, 5L, 20L, 15L, 13L, 3L, 18L, 11L, 9L, 6L, 10L, 7L), .Label = c("app", 
    "copilot", "get", "good", "great", "just", "like", "map", 
    "navig", "need", "new", "now", "road", "rout", "time", "updat", 
    "use", "version", "work", "year"), class = "factor"), pct3 = c(57.9, 
    45.7, 30.1, 21.7, 19.5, 19, 18.5, 18, 17.1, 16.7, 14.9, 14.6, 
    14, 12.7, 12.5, 12.2, 11.5, 10.9, 10.6, 10.5), words4 = structure(c(1L, 
    19L, 11L, 20L, 8L, 18L, 14L, 15L, 9L, 7L, 16L, 4L, 12L, 10L, 
    6L, 3L, 2L, 13L, 5L, 17L), .Label = c("app", "can", "doesnt", 
    "download", "even", "find", "get", "good", "great", "just", 
    "map", "navig", "navmii", "now", "rout", "time", "tri", "updat", 
    "use", "work"), class = "factor"), pct4 = c(56.1, 41.2, 36.5, 
    32.5, 22.6, 20.9, 18.9, 15.8, 14.9, 14.1, 14, 12.9, 12.4, 
    11.7, 11.3, 11.1, 10.9, 10.6, 10.3, 10.1), words5 = structure(c(1L, 
    4L, 19L, 10L, 6L, 11L, 20L, 2L, 16L, 18L, 12L, 17L, 5L, 8L, 
    9L, 15L, 14L, 3L, 13L, 7L), .Label = c("app", "best", "get", 
    "good", "gps", "great", "just", "like", "love", "map", "navig", 
    "nice", "now", "offlin", "rout", "sygic", "time", "updat", 
    "use", "work"), class = "factor"), pct5 = c(39.7, 23.5, 20.5, 
    19.3, 13.8, 11.3, 10.5, 10.2, 8.6, 7.7, 6.7, 6.7, 6.1, 6, 
    6, 5.9, 5.5, 5.1, 5, 4.9), words6 = structure(c(1L, 10L, 
    19L, 5L, 6L, 14L, 2L, 20L, 13L, 11L, 7L, 17L, 9L, 15L, 4L, 
    8L, 16L, 3L, 18L, 12L), .Label = c("app", "best", "can", 
    "download", "good", "great", "help", "like", "love", "map", 
    "navig", "need", "nice", "offlin", "rout", "thank", "travel", 
    "updat", "use", "work"), class = "factor"), pct6 = c(37.4, 
    26.4, 23, 20.7, 13.3, 13.2, 10.6, 9.1, 6.5, 6.1, 6, 6, 5.6, 
    5.4, 5.1, 5.1, 4.9, 4.9, 4.8, 4.6), words7 = structure(c(1L, 
    18L, 19L, 11L, 15L, 20L, 14L, 6L, 5L, 8L, 10L, 4L, 7L, 17L, 
    3L, 9L, 13L, 16L, 12L, 2L), .Label = c("app", "best", "drive", 
    "get", "good", "googl", "gps", "great", "like", "love", "map", 
    "navig", "road", "rout", "time", "traffic", "updat", "use", 
    "waze", "work"), class = "factor"), pct7 = c(57.9, 32.4, 
    24.6, 20.3, 18.9, 17.1, 15.9, 15.2, 12.8, 12.3, 12.2, 11.8, 
    11.8, 10.9, 10, 9.9, 9.7, 9.7, 9.4, 9.1), words8 = structure(c(1L, 
    12L, 19L, 15L, 6L, 13L, 2L, 20L, 9L, 5L, 7L, 18L, 11L, 16L, 
    10L, 17L, 8L, 14L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("app", "best", "better", 
    "can", "download", "good", "googl", "gps", "great", "like", 
    "love", "map", "navig", "need", "offlin", "rout", "time", 
    "updat", "use", "work"), class = "factor"), pct8 = c(44.6, 
    39.3, 25.2, 22.3, 18.5, 15.4, 15.4, 14.1, 12.6, 8.8, 8.7, 
    8.6, 7.3, 7.1, 6.8, 6.6, 6.6, 6.4, 6, 5.5)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

Data looks like this:

```
    words1 pct1   words2 pct2  words3 pct3   words4 pct4 words5 pct5   words6 pct6  words7 pct7   words8 pct8
1      app 70.8      app 69.1     app 57.9      app 56.1    app 39.7      app 37.4     app 57.9      app 44.6
2      map 40.4      use 32.9     use 45.7      use 41.2   good 23.5      map 26.4     use 32.4      map 39.3
3      use 26.4      map 27.3     map 30.1      map 36.5    use 20.5      use 23.0    waze 24.6      use 25.2
4     work 25.6     work 25.0    work 21.7     work 32.5    map 19.3     good 20.7     map 20.3   offlin 22.3
5     good 22.7   tomtom 21.4   updat 19.5     good 22.6  great 13.8    great 13.3    time 18.9     good 18.5
6    great 18.4     good 20.0    good 19.0    updat 20.9  navig 11.3   offlin 13.2    work 17.1    navig 15.4
7  connect 13.7    updat 16.6     now 18.5      now 18.9   work 10.5     best 10.6    rout 15.9     best 15.4
8  purchas 11.2    great 16.2    rout 18.0     rout 15.8   best 10.2     work  9.1   googl 15.2     work 14.1
9      can 10.8      tom 14.7 copilot 17.1    great 14.9  sygic  8.6     nice  6.5    good 12.8    great 12.6
10    like 10.8    phone 13.1   great 16.7      get 14.1  updat  7.7    navig  6.1   great 12.3 download  8.8
11   navig 10.8     time 13.0    year 14.9     time 14.0   nice  6.7     help  6.0    love 12.2    googl  8.7
12   phone 10.5     just 13.0    time 14.6 download 12.9   time  6.7   travel  6.0     get 11.8    updat  8.6
13    need 10.5      get 13.0    road 14.0    navig 12.4    gps  6.1     love  5.6     gps 11.8     love  7.3
14    dont 10.1      now 12.7     get 12.7     just 11.7   like  6.0     rout  5.4   updat 10.9     rout  7.1
15    free  9.4     year 12.2 version 12.5     find 11.3   love  6.0 download  5.1   drive 10.0     like  6.8
16     get  9.4    navig 11.8     new 12.2   doesnt 11.1   rout  5.9     like  5.1    like  9.9     time  6.6
17    road  9.0     need 11.2   navig 11.5      can 10.9 offlin  5.5    thank  4.9    road  9.7      gps  6.6
18   updat  8.3 download 10.4    just 10.9   navmii 10.6    get  5.1      can  4.9 traffic  9.7     need  6.4
19    rout  8.3     like 10.3    need 10.6     even 10.3    now  5.0    updat  4.8   navig  9.4      can  6.0
20     one  8.3     rout 10.2    like 10.5      tri 10.1   just  4.9     need  4.6    best  9.1   better  5.5
```

Data is about frequent words in reviews of 8 different offline navigation apps.

I have created small shiny application using following code (which works)

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

# Data Preparation Steps 
data <- read.csv("word_frequency_v2.csv")

my_colors2 <- c("#F29E4C", "#EFEA5A", "#6930C3", "#0077B6",
                "#F94144", "#16DB93", "#621708", "#DA627D")



ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Shiny - First Interactive Visualization Example"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
      
      selectInput(inputId="app1",label="App1",choices = c("Genius"="Genius",
                                                                        "TomTom"="TomTom",
                                                                        "CoPilot"="CoPilot",
                                                                        "Navmii"="Navmii",
                                                                        "Sygic"="Sygic",
                                                                        "Mapsme"="Mapsme",
                                                                        "Waze"="Waze",
                                                                        "Here"="Here"),
                  selected = "Genius",multiple = F),
      
      selectInput(inputId="app2",label="App2",choices = c("Genius"="Genius",
                                                          "TomTom"="TomTom",
                                                          "CoPilot"="CoPilot",
                                                          "Navmii"="Navmii",
                                                          "Sygic"="Sygic",
                                                          "Mapsme"="Mapsme",
                                                          "Waze"="Waze",
                                                          "Here"="Here"),
                  selected = "TomTom",multiple = F)
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Histogram ----
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot1"),
      plotOutput(outputId = "distPlot2")

    )
  )
)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram ----
server <- function(input, output){
  
  # 1. It is "reactive" and therefore should be automatically
  #    re-executed when inputs (input$bins) change
  # 2. Its output type is a plot
  
  output$distPlot1 <- renderPlot({
    
    p2 <- data %>% ggplot()
    if(input$app1 == "Genius"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1), fill = my_colors2[1]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1, label =pct1),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "TomTom"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2), fill = my_colors2[2]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2, label =pct2),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "CoPilot"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3), fill = my_colors2[3]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3, label =pct3),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Navmii"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4), fill = my_colors2[4]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4, label =pct4),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Sygic"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5), fill = my_colors2[5]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5, label =pct5),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Mapsme"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6), fill = my_colors2[6]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6, labe6 =pct6),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Waze"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7), fill = my_colors2[7]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7, label =pct7),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Here"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct8), y=pct8), fill = my_colors2[8]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct1), y=pct8, label =pct8),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }
    p2 <- p2 +  theme_bw()+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, face = "bold")) + 
      labs(x="Words",y="Share of words in reviews",title=paste("Frequency of words -",input$app1,sep = " "))
    
    p2
  })
  
  output$distPlot2 <- renderPlot({
    
    p2 <- data %>% ggplot()
    if(input$app2 == "Genius"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1), fill = my_colors2[1]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1, label =pct1),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "TomTom"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2), fill = my_colors2[2]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2, label =pct2),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "CoPilot"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3), fill = my_colors2[3]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3, label =pct3),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Navmii"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4), fill = my_colors2[4]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4, label =pct4),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Sygic"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5), fill = my_colors2[5]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5, label =pct5),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Mapsme"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6), fill = my_colors2[6]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6, label =pct6),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Waze"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7), fill = my_colors2[7]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7, label =pct7),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Here"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct8), y=pct8), fill = my_colors2[8]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct8), y=pct8, label =pct8),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }
    p2 <- p2 +  theme_bw()+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, face = "bold")) + 
      labs(x="Words",y="Share of words in reviews",title=paste("Frequency of words -",input$app2,sep = " "))
    
    p2
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Now I'm trying to use that code and incorporate it to my already existing flexdashboard using the follwoing code, but I can't manage to make it work.

````
---
title: "Shiny in flexdashboard"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny      
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
```

```{r}
#Import data
data <- read.csv("word_frequency_v2.csv")
my_colors2 <- c("#F29E4C", "#EFEA5A", "#6930C3", "#0077B6",
                "#F94144", "#16DB93", "#621708", "#DA627D")
```

# Word frequency

### Embedding a Shiny Module {.sidebar}

```{r, include=FALSE}
selectInput(inputId="app1",label="App1",choices = c("Genius"="Genius",
                                                    "TomTom"="TomTom",
                                                    "CoPilot"="CoPilot",
                                                    "Navmii"="Navmii",
                                                    "Sygic"="Sygic",
                                                    "Mapsme"="Mapsme",
                                                    "Waze"="Waze",
                                                    "Here"="Here"),
            selected = "Genius",multiple = F)
      
selectInput(inputId="app2",label="App2",choices = c("Genius"="Genius",
                                                    "TomTom"="TomTom",
                                                    "CoPilot"="CoPilot",
                                                    "Navmii"="Navmii",
                                                    "Sygic"="Sygic",
                                                    "Mapsme"="Mapsme",
                                                    "Waze"="Waze",
                                                    "Here"="Here"),
            selected = "TomTom",multiple = F)
```

```{r, include=FALSE}
renderPlot({
    
    p2 <- data %>% ggplot()
    if(input$app1 == "Genius"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1), fill = my_colors2[1]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1, label =pct1),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "TomTom"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2), fill = my_colors2[2]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2, label =pct2),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "CoPilot"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3), fill = my_colors2[3]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3, label =pct3),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Navmii"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4), fill = my_colors2[4]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4, label =pct4),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Sygic"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5), fill = my_colors2[5]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5, label =pct5),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Mapsme"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6), fill = my_colors2[6]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6, labe6 =pct6),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Waze"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7), fill = my_colors2[7]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7, label =pct7),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app1 == "Here"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct8), y=pct8), fill = my_colors2[8]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct1), y=pct8, label =pct8),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }
    p2 <- p2 +  theme_bw()+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, face = "bold")) + 
      labs(x="Words",y="Share of words in reviews",title=paste("Frequency of words -",input$app1,sep = " "))
    
    p2
  })
  
renderPlot({
    
    p2 <- data %>% ggplot()
    if(input$app2 == "Genius"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1), fill = my_colors2[1]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words1, -pct1), y=pct1, label =pct1),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "TomTom"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2), fill = my_colors2[2]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words2, -pct2), y=pct2, label =pct2),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "CoPilot"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3), fill = my_colors2[3]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words3, -pct3), y=pct3, label =pct3),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Navmii"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4), fill = my_colors2[4]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words4, -pct4), y=pct4, label =pct4),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Sygic"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5), fill = my_colors2[5]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words5, -pct5), y=pct5, label =pct5),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Mapsme"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6), fill = my_colors2[6]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words6, -pct6), y=pct6, label =pct6),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Waze"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7), fill = my_colors2[7]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words7, -pct7), y=pct7, label =pct7),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }else if(input$app2 == "Here"){
      p2 <- p2 + geom_col(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct8), y=pct8), fill = my_colors2[8]) +
        geom_text(aes(x=reorder(words8, -pct8), y=pct8, label =pct8),
                  position = position_dodge(0.9), size = 3.5, fontface = "bold", vjust = -1)
    }
    p2 <- p2 +  theme_bw()+
      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,100), expand = c(0, 0)) +
      theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
            panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
            plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
            axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1, face = "bold")) + 
      labs(x="Words",y="Share of words in reviews",title=paste("Frequency of words -",input$app2,sep = " "))
    
    p2
  })
```
````

If I run `rmarkdown:render("filename.Rmd")` I get the following error:path for html_dependency not provided

If I run `rmarkdown:run("filename.Rmd")` I get an app which doesn't show any filters nor charts.
I would like to run the render function if possible since I used to do that with my previous flexdashboard and everything looks better if I export the dashboard to .html file.

Comment: Possible dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44262479/3358272. Try `rmarkdown::run` instead of `rmarkdown::render` (I don't *know* that this works, just a thought.)

Comment: Hi.
Thank you for your answers. I can run `rmarkdown::run`. I get no errors but I also get a webpage with defined dashboard name, sidebar, mainbar but no inputs (filters) and outputs (charts) are there.
You can try and run my code, I have tried to make it reproducible.

Comment: Please replace your data with either an available R dataset or with a sample of it using `dput`.

Comment: Hi
I have edited my post and copied data from the console. It is not big - 20 observations and 16 variables only. Hope that this helps